# Header Footer Content Adjustment

Tags: header-footer

Throughout my document i want to print CHAPTER number on the left header and CHAPTER TITLE on the right header. I have tried leftmark command but it is not as i want it to be. Kindly Help

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Where, if anywhere, should page numbers be displayed?

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility with `fancyhdr`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter\hfill#1}{}}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

or with `scrlayer-scrpage`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text

\usepackage[automark,headsepline,markcase=noupper]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\renewcommand{\chaptermarkformat}{\chaptername\ \thechapter\hfill}
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\upshape}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\leftmark}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

with the same result as above.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you might be looking for is in the fancyhdr package.

With this package you can edit your headers using commands found in the documentation.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\lhead{\chaptername\ \thechapter}

\begin{document}

\chapter{TestingHeaders}
some text to test \\
\lipsum[1-10] 
the test is concluded.\\

\end{document}
```

Regards,
Thomas